# How to print out a newline character in a string in Awk

Tags: unix, awk

Tried googling everywhere and I couldn't find anything. I'm trying to figure this out...how would one print out the actual \n char at the end of a line so that in the output file it comes out:

stuff stuff stuff \n
stuff stuff stuff \n
stuff stuff stuff \n
stuff stuff stuff \n

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Show the code you're currently using to generate that, it may be improper use, typos, etc.

Comment: Beyond the obvious `gsub(/$/, "\\n")`? http://ideone.com/p2e7S4

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I believe that all you would have to do is escape the slash in `\n` in the following way: `\\n`.

Here is a simple example:

```
ll | awk '{ printf "%s\\n\n",$1 }'
```

This should print the permissions column for each file in the current directory and after each line of input, a literal newline character `\n` is inserted after which an actual newline is inserted.

The result should look something like this:

```
drwxrwxr-x.\n
-rw-rw-r--.\n
-rw-rw-r--.\n
-rwxrwxr-x.\n
-rwxrwxr-x.\n
drwxrwxr-x.\n
drwxrwxr-x.\n
```

As you can see, there is a literal `\n` at the end of each line.

---

If you don't want any "real" newline characters and have all of your output on one line, you can remove the second `\n` from the `printf` statement:

```
ll | awk '{ printf "%s\\n",$1 }'
```

This will give you output very similar to what you mentioned in your question with a literal `\n` appended to each input line:

```
\n-rwxrwxr-x.\ndrwxrwxr-x.\n-rw-rw-r--.\n-rwxrwxr-x.\ndrwxrwxr-x.\n-rw-rw-r--.\ndrwxrwxr-x.\n-rw-rw-r--.\n
```

Comment: Totally sorry...I'm going to edit this, but I should have rephrased it so that it said at the end of each line. Would you happen to have any help in that regard?

Comment: You would do exactly the same thing - escaping the newline character by adding an extra slash: `\\n`.

Comment: Take a look at my edits - perhaps this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yup! That did it! Thank you so much!

Comment: @user3521858 - you are very welcome! Happy scripting!